# How to efficiently index multiple nested numbers in JSONB structure with PostgreSQL for efficient comparison operations? (optional: SQLAlchemy)

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sqlalchemy, nested, jsonb

I want to make sure PostgreSQL indexing works properly (B-Tree, to allow efficient greater than / smaller than operations on numbers) inside a JSONB on multiple nested numbers. The JSONB "data" column would look as follows:

```
data: {
    a: {n: 1000, str: 'blabla'},
    b: {n: 2000, str: 'blabla'},
    c: {n: 3000, str: 'blabla'},
    d: {n: 4000, str: 'blabla'},

    ...[we can assume 10 such nested dicts]
}
```

Where I would select rows based on combinations of multiple nested numbers, ex:

```
WHERE data['a']['n'] == 1000
AND data['b']['n'] == 2000
AND data['c']['n'] >= 3000
AND data['d']['n'] <= 4000
```

and adding multiple ORDER BYs such as:

```
ORDER BY DESC(data['a']['n']) + DESC(data['b']['n']) etc.
```

to achieve ordering based on the a, b, c, d hierarchy and nested numbers 'n' in ascending or descending order.

I've put some code below, but I can't tell if the indexing is working as expected and I'm wondering if this is the right way or if there's a better way to achieve this? (ideally using JSONB)

I'm using PostgreSQL 11 (with SQLAlchemy ORM), so the table and index declaration look as per below:

```py
class TableWithJSONB(db.Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tablewithjsonb'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(NestedMutable.as_mutable(JSONB), nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = ( # Adding Indexes
        # GIN using jsonb_path_ops => are these indexes useful?
        Index(
            'ix_data_a_gin',
            text("(data->'a') jsonb_path_ops"),
            postgresql_using='gin',
        ),
        Index(
            'ix_data_b_gin',
            text("(data->'b') jsonb_path_ops"),
            postgresql_using='gin',
        ),
        Index(
            'ix_data_c_gin',
            text("(data->'c') jsonb_path_ops"),
            postgresql_using='gin',
        ),
        ...


        # BTree Indexes on nested numbers
        Index(
            'ix_data_a_bTree',
            text("((data #> '{a, n}')::INTEGER) int4_ops"),
        ),
        # BTree Indexes on nested numbers
        Index(
            'ix_data_b_bTree',
            text("((data #> '{b, n}')::INTEGER) int4_ops"),
        ),
        # BTree Indexes on nested numbers
        Index(
            'ix_data_c_bTree',
            text("((data #> '{c, n}')::INTEGER) int4_ops"),
        ),
        ...
    )
```

After reading what I could find on the subject, I'm not sure if the b-Tree index actually works as expected for each nested numerical value inside JSONB. Also, I can't tell if the GIN jsonb_path_ops index makes any sense on the nested dicts a, b, c, d for the usage described above. Is this the right way or is there a better way?

**UPDATE**: I seem to have answered my own question. See *dbfiddle* [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6961212a59dc24f44d0d40a921b82ea3)

**Indexing nested numeric value in JSONB** (with b-Tree index):

```
CREATE INDEX i_btree_a ON tablewithjsonb (((data #> '{a, n}')::INTEGER) int4_ops);
```

Successfully creates index on the numeric value *data['a']['n']* in JSONB.

The index is used with queries such as:

```
explain analyze select * from tablewithjsonb
    where (data #> '{a, n}')::INTEGER  <= 10000;
```

Creating a combined index on multiple numeric values within the same JSONB works as well (in this particular case the index above (*i_btree_a*) would be redundant, searching on *data['a']['n']* would use the index *i_btree_a_b* below instead):

```
CREATE INDEX i_btree_a_b ON tablewithjsonb
    (((data #> '{a, n}')::INTEGER) int4_ops,
    ((data #> '{b, n}')::INTEGER) int4_ops);
```

..which would be used on queries such as:

```
explain analyze select * from tablewithjsonb
    where (data #> '{a, n}')::INTEGER  <= 10000 AND
    where (data #> '{b, n}')::INTEGER  <= 10000;
```

**Indexing nested string/text value in JSONB** (with b-Tree index):

```
CREATE INDEX i_btree_s_a ON tablewithjsonb ((data #>> '{a, s}'));
```

The b-Tree index will be used for equality (=) and LIKE operations (Execution Time: 0.048 ms):

```
explain analyze select * from tablewithjsonb
    where (data #>> '{a, s}') = 'blabla';
explain analyze select * from tablewithjsonb
    where (data #>> '{a, s}') LIKE '%blabla%';
```

(*Update: when I tried this separately, it went for sequential scan instead of index. Why?*)

Although I don't understand why the following goes for a sequential scan (Execution Time: 53.712 ms) (**why?**):

```
explain analyze select * from tablewithjsonb
    where (data #>> '{a, s}')  LIKE '%blabla 1 5%';
```

**Indexing nested string/text value in JSONB** (with GIN full text search index):

```
CREATE INDEX i_gin_ts_s_a ON tablewithjsonb
    USING GIN (( to_tsvector('english', (data #>> '{a, s}')) ));
```

The GIN full text search index will be used for queries as such:

```
explain analyze select * from tablewithjsonb where
    to_tsvector('english', (data #>> '{a, s}')) @@ to_tsquery('blabla & 1 & 5:*');
```

(Execution Time: 34.845 ms)

I note that this last query (via GIN full-text search) is quite slow (**why?**), not far from the sequential scan mentioned above where Execution Time was 53.712 ms.

Comment: Since the JSON data is so regular, consider whether the complication of JSONB is necessary. Consider instead two tables. One to store the key, n, and str. The other a join table to group them together.

Comment: Thank you Schwern for the suggestion. In the meantime I'm still using JSON because the structure may be changing / evolving for this particular aspect and I need to remain flexible.